# /proc/<pid>/fd/1 shows nothing

Tags: proc, debugging

I'm running `ddrescue` on my notebook and I'm trying to capture the output in the console from another console. So I tried running

```
sudo tail -f /proc/<pidOfDdrescue>/fd/1
```

where "`<pidOfDdrescue>`" was substituted with the PID of ddrescue.
But nothing happens (nothing will be printed). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: And what's the output of `ls -l /proc/PIDofddrescue/fd/1`? If it's not a symlink to a regular file, that can't work.

Comment: The output is `/proc/<pid>/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/2`

Comment: Run `ps` in the second terminal to find out its `pts`, then run in the first console: `ddrescue ... 2>&1 | tee /dev/pts/...`.

Comment: @MarkM, that's a tty device. When you read from a tty device (like your tail -f does here), you read whatever data is typed on the keyboard at the terminal connected behind that device, not what applications (like ddrescue here) are sending there for the terminal to display.